# Bigger stage vs scrolling background

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, background, smoothing, stage

I'm making a flash game, and I can't decide to use a bigger stage or a smaller one, with scrolling background to make it run smoother. I's going to be some kind of strategy game if it matters.

Thanks

Comment: Many , many variables that will performance. Smaller stage area will make it faster. so will a lower frame-rate.  Using GPU accelration can help a bit, use Stage3D can help a LOT (thing like the starling framework)

Comment: wow, using starling framework make it use the GPU? and how optimized the framework is?

Comment: The framework runs very well, especially noticeable on mobile where every bit of optimization helps.  If you search the web you will find lots of praise for starling. Lots of good tutorials on how to use it as well.

Comment: okay now, im gonna check this framework out, anyways I can't accept the answers cause they aren't answers to the question, so please write something more fitting to it, so i can give you the points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many, many variables that determine the performance of your application.

To answer your question, a smaller stage area will make your program run faster.  The amount of difference will depend on the way your application deals with display objects.  Flash will not render things that are completely outside the stage bounds.  So keeping only those objects that are needed at any given time on the stage is a good practice.

using flash player 11's new [stage3D](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/games/gaming_engines.html) features (even for 2D stuff) will likely make your game very smooth.  Lots of good frameworks out there that can take care of the low-level stuff if you don't want to get into it. For 2D, [starling](http://gamua.com/starling/) is very easy to get started with, and seems to be Adobe's favored framework.

At a bare minimum, make sure you use GPU acceleration in your output/compiler options.

There are LOTS of other tips for optimization people could get into, but that is better suited for google searches as Stackoverflow is about specific questions.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to have a bitmap object the size of your stage for example 800x600, then draw your objects into the bitmapdata of that bitmap using copyPixels this is known as blitting and is pretty fast.

Another option is to just use the flash display list and add every object as sprites onto the stage.

Second method is easier to handle in terms of mouse events and stuff.

My advice is to start with the second option and see if performance is enough, if not go with option 1.